# Find corresponding nodes in two geometrical graphs

Tags: python, networkx

I have two graphs A,B each with 160 nodes but different labels. Each node has a position pos = (x,y,z) and an orientation (a1, a2, a3). 
Now I want to find an optimal label matching of these two graphs. The graphs are obtained by a triangulation of the x and y coordinates (I am sure one can do better by leveraging the z coordinate, but this graph should suffice for now). 
To give you a better intuition, here are the images of the graphs :
[image: graph A]
[image: graph B]

With which methods can I analyze the graphs and find an optimal matching (relabeling) such that similar nodes in graph A and graph B have similar position, orientation and graph properties like degree of the nodes. 
I already tried to solve it with `scipy.optimize` as a linear programming problem (`linear_sum_assignment(dist_nodes_A_to_B)`) (`dist_nodes_A_to_B` is a 160x160 matrix containing the L2 distance of nodes i from A and j from B: `dist_nodes_A_to_B[i,j]=sum(A.i.pos-B.j.pos)**2 )`), but that yields inferior results.

Maybe the `networkx` library can help here, but I am not familiar with the library. I don't necessarily  look for a concrete solution but rather for the name of algorithms which might help to solve the problem. If this question is inappropriate for SO, tell me where I can ask it.

Comment: Recommend posting this question on the [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) StackExchange site.

Comment: [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140813/what-is-a-good-algorithm-to-measure-similarity-between-two-dynamic-graphs) might be helpful

Comment: In which sense are the results of `linear_sum_assignment` inferior? And note that if you want to include "orientation", you could use the full 6-dimensional space when calculating distances as well.